# Track requests causing timeouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rack, unicorn

I'm experiencing quite a few of these in my production logs:

```
E, [2016-01-24T20:34:44.862096 #21631] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 23077 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=10
E, [2016-01-24T20:34:44.862282 #21631] ERROR -- : worker=12 PID:23064 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2016-01-24T20:34:44.876932 #21631] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 23064 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=12
I, [2016-01-24T20:34:44.895914 #23619]  INFO -- : worker=12 ready
```

i'm using both New Relic and Honeybadger to track errors, however since the Unicorn worker get's killed, I cannot figure out what requests are taking so long.

I tried implementing the middleware described in [this](http://underthehood.meltwater.com/blog/2014/03/21/debugging-unicorn-rails-timeouts/) blog post, however it throws the following error when testing it out in local dev:

```
I, [2016-01-24T21:22:08.453846 #63197]  INFO -- : [cc042b92-0530-4c9c-9503-73bba529fe20] Completed 200 OK in 1061ms (Views: 1016.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
F, [2016-01-24T21:22:08.458914 #63197] FATAL -- : [cc042b92-0530-4c9c-9503-73bba529fe20] 
ThreadError (killed thread):
  config/initializers/log_before_timeout.rb:19:in `run'
  config/initializers/log_before_timeout.rb:19:in `call'
```

What can I do to fix this? Alternatively, is there a better way about inspecting this?

**BTW** I did not used default rails server (webbrick) to test it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to run the thread at the ensure block not `thr.run`

```
Thread.current.run
```